# Intent and Emulator Transitions

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making this app which shows things you own and about those things you own. So far I have made a button showing the "Garage" that you own. I have added an intent which transitions from "Garage" to another page on the app showing the two vehicles you own, which is a Camaro and a Mustang. From there I want it to go from Camaro > about the Camaro and with the Mustang I want it to go from the Mustang > about the Mustang. So far I have an intent which transitions from Camaro and Mustang to another page showing about them, but I want to keep them seperated. When I click both Camaro or Mustang buttons they transition to the same page. What my problem is, is that I can't figure out how to get them both on seperate pages. I'm sorry if this is confusing at first, but I will try to put all the pictures and code in the best order I can to make it easier to understand.

This is the first page of the app:

[image]

This is the code to the first page:

[image]

This is what the first page transitions too, which is mustang and camaro. I want to figure out how to transition both buttons, mustang and camaro to transition to their own pages:

[image]

Here is the code to mustang and camaro:

[image]

This is what page Mustang and Camaro transitions too:

[image]

Either button I click it transitions to this page. I want both mustang and camaro buttons to transition to different pages. How exactly would i make it to where both Mustang, and Camaro buttons transition to their own seperate pages?

Here is the code to about mustang and camaro:
[image]

P.S i apoligize if this is confusing or is lacking information or questions. i've put a lot of time into this and am banging my head on the wall trying to figure this out. I am also having a hard time finding information about this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways of approaching this problem

1. Create activity pages for both mustang and camaro ***(not recommended)*** then set your onclick listener to each of the corresponding page
2. Pass data to the Act3Activity page! Before starting your intent, do

`myIntent.putExtra(car_name, "camaro");`  pass a string to the intent, depends on which car button you clicked, for example, camaro in this case

Start the intent and retrieve the data in Act3Activity by doing

```
String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getString("car_name");
```

Then you will know which car you picked, add a switch statement in Act3Activity

```
switch(car_name):
    case "camaro":
        // add info related to camaro to a string
        break;
    case "mustang":
        // add info related to mustang to a string 
        break;
```

Show the string in a textView or Toast?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is you have the same click listener attached to both buttons.  Either attach a different click listener to each of the buttons(don't use "this" as the listener, create separate listener objects), or examine the view that is passed as the argument to onClick to determine which button was clicked and use a different intent for each of the buttons.

A better answer, though, is you need to redesign your application.  Surely you do not intend to create a new activity for every item you own.   There are many better ways this could be designed, but that is beyond the scope of your question.